# Need help deciphering these logs regarding YASSL attack on MySQL

Tags: apache, mysql, python

I am getting the occasional message from our Fortigate Fortinet firewall, indicating that there is a `yaSSL.Buffer.Overflow` attack.  The log from the Fortinet is:

```
Description: Subject: attack:MySQL.yaSSL.Buffer.Overflow
Device: cid7543-chi-fw0
Severity: critical
From: TP-DA2-CleanIPFAZ-01(FAZ-VM0000168142)
Trigger: Detected IPS - High Severity - SNOW
logver=0700090444 
idseq=88564181531365481 
itime=1675946425 
devid="FGVM2VTM22004997" 
devname="cid7543-chi-fw0" 
vd="root" 
date=2023-02-09 
time=06:40:25 
eventtime=1675946426090368217 
tz="-0600" 
logid="0419016384" 
type="utm" 
subtype="ips" 
eventtype="signature" 
level="alert" 
severity="high" 
srcip=34.76.158.233 
srccountry="Belgium" 
dstip=10.2.0.2 
dstcountry="Reserved" 
srcintf="port1" 
srcintfrole="undefined" 
dstintf="port2" 
dstintfrole="undefined" 
sessionid=62985862 
action="detected" 
proto=6 
service="MYSQL" 
policyid=6 
poluuid="2fe1c1c8-69f2-51ed-e303-35be37ae7cfd" 
policytype="policy" 
attack="MySQL.yaSSL.Buffer.Overflow" 
srcport=33830 
dstport=3306 
direction="outgoing" 
attackid=15252 
profile="CleanIP-ips-windows-srv" 
ref="http://www.fortinet.com/ids/VID15252" 
incidentserialno=193399204 
msg="database: MySQL.yaSSL.Buffer.Overflow" 
crscore=30 
craction=8192 
crlevel="high"
```

With that said, I decided to search for the offending IP in my logs on the server:

```
ack '34.76.158.233'
```

With the results of:

```
12807:Feb  9 05:28:21 WebServer kernel: [21753283.222680] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:08:0d:03:00:50:56:08:18:9f:08:00 SRC=34.76.158.233 DST=10.2.6.40 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x60 TTL=64 ID=64049 PROTO=TCP SPT=39094 DPT=21 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

kern.log
12807:Feb  9 05:28:21 WebServer kernel: [21753283.222680] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:08:0d:03:00:50:56:08:18:9f:08:00 SRC=34.76.158.233 DST=10.2.6.40 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x60 TTL=64 ID=64049 PROTO=TCP SPT=39094 DPT=21 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

apache2/access.log
11:34.76.158.233 - - [09/Feb/2023:07:08:49 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 218 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"

auth.log
83214:Feb  9 18:40:31 WebServer sudo:      zak : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/var/log ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/ack 34.76.158.233

syslog.1
4759:Feb  9 05:28:21 WebServer kernel: [21753283.222680] [UFW BLOCK] IN=ens32 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:08:0d:03:00:50:56:08:18:9f:08:00 SRC=34.76.158.233 DST=10.2.6.40 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x60 TTL=64 ID=64049 PROTO=TCP SPT=39094 DPT=21 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

mysql/error.log
3:2023-02-09T12:40:26.035108Z 188497 [Warning] IP address '34.76.158.233' has been resolved to the host name '233.158.76.34.bc.googleusercontent.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
4:2023-02-09T12:40:26.341330Z 188497 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'34.76.158.233' (using password: NO)
```

How can I go about tracking the actual injection point and determine the action that needs to be taken?  I realize that the Fortigate caught the attack, I'd just like to pretend the firewall wasn't there and fix the vulnerability properly.

Comment: Why are you thinking that there is an injection point? All I'm seeing is an attempt to exploit. No injection.

Comment: I know this is old ..  @schroeder -- But you were 100% correct.  The logs only indicated an attempt, the server was not vulnerable, and in fact the attempt was blocked by the firewall ..  We since tightened up security to only allow US based IPs (we are a local US based company that does zero business overseas) and the logs entries pretty much stopped all together, so, double win.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to resolve.

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to prevent this vulnerability ( If there is no firewall ) the first thing you need to do is always keep eye on what version of service you are running because if you don't know what's going on you can't understand what step you should take to prevent or you'll never know that vulnerability even exists in your system, You might wonder it's not possible to keep eye on every service right?

At this point, I will say you should start with Vulnerability Scanner to keep eye on the services that you are running using vulnerability scanner tools such as OpenVAS, Nessus, and Qualys, these have free versions for each.

Or you might be considering checking for updates regularly and upgrading to the latest version of the services as soon as they become available.

Sometimes the vulnerability may take time to patch from the developer at that time you need to look at logs for unusual activities you can use Splunk ( Free with limited features ), Then implement a firewall like right now you using "Fortigate Fortinet firewall".

Once you get to know that something went wrong then take steps on that service might upgrade to the latest patch or implement a firewall.

Now let's talk about this vulnerability you posted, From **Rapid7** ( [ref](https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/mysql-yassl-multiple-bof/) ) they said that **"MySQL yaSSL Buffer Overflow"** allows remote attackers to cause a denial of service (crash) via a Hello packet containing a large size value, which triggers a buffer over-read in the HASHwithTransform::Update function in `hash.cpp` and its solution is to upgrade MySQL to `mysql-upgrade-5_0_54a`, `mysql-upgrade-5_1_23`, `mysql-upgrade-6_0_4a`

You know that this vulnerability exists because of the Firewall log, If it wasn't there you need to follow the above steps I've said to know more about your services.

Comment: I did not downvote you -- BUT .. My question, is barring the upgrade (Which I know should happen, but Magento doesn't support PHP 8, MySQL 8 yet) -- The real question is, how can I track what the attacker actually DID based on the logs? **How can I go about tracking the actual injection point?**

Comment: The other problem here is that the firewall log does not indicate a *vulnerability* but an *attack*.

Comment: @Zak if you read the answer here, I have reffed the Rapid7 and I forget to added https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/16701 this exploit link that can help you to exploit, This just sends Hello packet with large containts of value that results DoS the mysql service. So, There is no endpoint available for injection because this exploit I provided only sends packets and tracking down attacker is check logs simply if they get access through any injection the log will be added in /var/logs/*.log folder

Comment: Your answer depends on the MySQL server having this vulnerability. The logs don't indicate that. The longs only indicate that someone tried to to exploit this specific vulnerability. And, as the OP mentioned, this doesn't answer the question about the "injection point" so this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: he didn't get it at first that's the reason he was looking for if "injection point" was available or something.